# How to get undefined nasted mongoose objects (or subdocuments)?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, realm

I'm working on the backend side with MongoDB and NodeJs. Frontend team who works with Android and Realm database requires undefined subdocuments, but MongoDB does not return it. I tried to use "populate", but if object is undefined I receive internal server error.

For example I have this nasted object:

```
location: {
    latitude: {
        type: Number
    },
    longitude: {
        type: Number
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
```

When I call Event.find(...) if location is undefined then returned JSON object (under execution callback function)  does not contain location at all in its body. Is there any way to retrive all model attributes even if they are undefined?

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here to answer this question.

Comment: I have extended my question, I hope that it is more understandable now. :)

Comment: So it should be set to `null` instead of just not provided?

Comment: Yes, for example: location: { latitude: null, longitude: null, name: null}